# Is it possible to auto- upload/merge files from a SharePoint folder in PowerBI?

Tags: sharepoint, powerbi, powerquery

I have a site in sharepoint with a main folders and sub folders where I store some monthly .csv files. There a a total of three subfolders with files that gets a new file every month. The files are the same structure every month.

I have managed to merge the files in Power Query which works well despite slow query times with SharePoint.

Now to my question:
Is it possible for Power BI to automatically include and merge new files when they are uploaded or will I have to manually edit the query monthly?

If this is not possible, what are the best alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

This is straight forward using custom functions.

1. Import the file once and create a custom function out of your steps
2. Filter all your import files using the SharePoint connector
3. Add column by invoking your custom function
4. Expand the results

This way you are **appending** your data files to one table, but I would be surprised if you actually need to **merge** them.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write out this reply.

After importing multiple files though the 'SharePoint Folder' connector, the string created in "Advanced Editor" will all of the files specifically.

Currently, I need to go and manually add the name of the new file for the file to be added. The file is then added to the existing table without issues.

I may be missing something here but wouldn't your solution result in the same issue?

Comment: No, you only have to filter all the files you want to import by name pattern or subfolder and either read the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/custom-function or offer a job to someone else.